# Reading in input to construct an object

Tags: c++, object, stream

I am trying to read a string line for line down a .txt file in order to initiate an array of objects using a constructor that takes a string.

The text file is written like

`TransAm`
`Mustang`
`Corvette`

I feel like my loop is not iterating the information I want to be set correctly. Is there an easy way of accomplishing this?
main.cc

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Car.cc"
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

        Car cars[3];


        string STRING;
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("cars.txt");

// THIS IS HOW IT'S ACHIEVED USING FOR-LOOP - Sam

for(int i = 0; i<3 && infile;++i){
            getline(infile,STRING);
            cars[i].setName(STRING);
    }


/* THIS IS WHAT I HAD
        while(!infile)
        {
            getline(infile,STRING);
            for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(cars);i++){
                cars[i].setName(STRING);
            }
        }
  */  
        infile.close();
        for(int j = 0;j<sizeof(cars);j++){
            cars[j].print();
        }

    }
```

Car.h

```
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class Car{

public:
    Car();
    Car(string);
    string getName();
    void setName(string);
    void print();

private:
    string name;
};
```

Car.cc

```
#include <string>
#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;

 Car::Car()
 {

 }

 Car::Car(string s)
{
     setName(s);
}

void Car::setName(string s)
{
    name = s;
}

string Car::getName()
{
    return name;
}

void Car::print()
{
    cout << name;
}
```

Comment: `while(!infile)` I feel like your loop does nothing at all.

Comment: Change `while(!infile)` to `while(getline(infile,STRING))`

Comment: I'm trying a while loop but the result fails to read and set "Trans-Am"

`while(infile)
 {
  for(int i = 0; i < 3 && infile; ++i){
   getline(infile,STRING);
   cars[i].setName(STRING);
  }
 }`

Comment: btw it would be nice if you decapitalize the name `STRING` and replace it with something like `line` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These points need to be corrected:

1. `while (!infile)` prevents you from entering the loop.
2. You don't need two loops.

You can modify your loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cars) && getline(infile, STRING); ++i)
    cars[i].setName(STRING);
```

Or like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cars) && infile; ++i) {
    getline(infile, STRING);
    cars[i].setName(STRING);
}
```

Comment: I wish you didn't delete your previous edits. It was really neat seeing the different ways I could approach this as you updated them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As it's been said, "Change while(!infile) to while(getline(infile,STRING))" but do not forget to remove the getline(infile,STRING); afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop does at the moment nothing if the file is correctly opened. It will only enter if the call to open was unsuccessful.

Change your loop to either

```
while (getline(infile,STRING))
{
    //...
}
```

or

```
while (infile)
{
    //...
}
```